# How can create animation from recursive lineTo calling in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

this code generating hilbert curve in a canvas, I'm trying to create an animation from it in everytime `ctx.lineTo` is called. I tried many solutions using `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame` but none of them works.

Here's code:

```js
const bw = 904;
const bh = 820;
const pixelX = 10;

const canvas = document.getElementById("board");
canvas.setAttribute("width", bw);
canvas.setAttribute("height", bh);

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const hilbertCurve = (x, y, Xi, Xj, Yi, Yj, n) => {
  if (n < 0) {
    ctx.lineTo(x + (Xi + Yi) / 2, y + (Xj + Yj) / 2);
  } else {
    hilbertCurve(x, y, Yi / 2, Yj / 2, Xi / 2, Xj / 2, n - 1);
    hilbertCurve(x + Xi / 2, y + Xj / 2, Xi / 2, Xj / 2, Yi / 2, Yj / 2, n - 1);
    hilbertCurve(
      x + Xi / 2 + Yi / 2,
      y + Xj / 2 + Yj / 2,
      Xi / 2,
      Xj / 2,
      Yi / 2,
      Yj / 2,
      n - 1
    );
    hilbertCurve(
      x + Xi / 2 + Yi,
      y + Xj / 2 + Yj,
      -Yi / 2,
      -Yj / 2,
      -Xi / 2,
      -Xj / 2,
      n - 1
    );
  }
};

function draw() {
  ctx.beginPath();
  hilbertCurve(0, 0, bw, 0, 0, bh, 7);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.stroke();
}

function init() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

init();
```

```html
<canvas id="board"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution is to use a `stroke-dash-array` trick that people used to SVG will already know.
We only define the path, set the `stroke-dash-array` to the length of our path, then at each iteration we increase the `stroke-dash-offset` to make it seem it draws continuously.

The biggest problem with this solution is that we need to be able to get the length of our path...

Unfortunately, and for I don't know what reasons, [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/) interface doesn't offer any easy means to do so. SVGGeometryElement on the other hand has a very handy [`getTotalLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getTotalLength) method.
Path2d and svg <path> elements can accept the same string path definition, so we can simply make your `hilbertCurve` function return a string definition, and then use this string both for an svg <path> and for a Path2D object drawable on our context.

```js
const bw = 904;
const bh = 820;
const pixelX = 10;

let path_as_string = "" + hilbertCurve( 0, 0, bw, 0, 0, bh, 7).replace('L', 'M');

const path = new Path2D( path_as_string );
const speed = 5;
const totalLength = getPathLength( path_as_string );

let offset = 0;
const canvas = document.getElementById("board");
canvas.setAttribute("width", bw);
canvas.setAttribute("height", bh);

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function hilbertCurve( x, y, Xi, Xj, Yi, Yj, n ) {
  if (n < 0) {
    return "L" + (x + (Xi + Yi) / 2) + "," + (y + (Xj + Yj) / 2);
  } else {
    return (
      hilbertCurve(x, y, Yi / 2, Yj / 2, Xi / 2, Xj / 2, n - 1) +
      hilbertCurve(x + Xi / 2, y + Xj / 2, Xi / 2, Xj / 2, Yi / 2, Yj / 2, n - 1) +
      hilbertCurve(
        x + Xi / 2 + Yi / 2,
        y + Xj / 2 + Yj / 2,
        Xi / 2,
        Xj / 2,
        Yi / 2,
        Yj / 2,
        n - 1
      ) +
      hilbertCurve(
        x + Xi / 2 + Yi,
        y + Xj / 2 + Yj,
        -Yi / 2,
        -Yj / 2,
        -Xi / 2,
        -Xj / 2,
        n - 1
      )
    );
  }
};

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
  ctx.lineDashOffset = offset;
  ctx.stroke(path);

  offset += speed;
  if( offset < totalLength ) {
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }
}

function init() {
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.setLineDash( [ 0, totalLength, totalLength ] );
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

init();

// returns the length of a path from a string definition
function getPathLength( path ) {
  const elem = document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path' );
  elem.setAttribute( 'd', path );
  return elem.getTotalLength();
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
The animation starts at the bottom left corner<br>
<canvas id="board"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer I just get.

```js
const bw = 904;
const bh = 820;
const pixelX = 10;

const canvas = document.getElementById("board");
canvas.setAttribute("width", bw);
canvas.setAttribute("height", bh);
const lines = [];

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const hilbertCurve = (x, y, Xi, Xj, Yi, Yj, n) => {
  if (n < 0) {
    lines.push({ x, Xi, Xj, y, Yi, Yj });
  } else {
    hilbertCurve(x, y, Yi / 2, Yj / 2, Xi / 2, Xj / 2, n - 1);
    hilbertCurve(x + Xi / 2, y + Xj / 2, Xi / 2, Xj / 2, Yi / 2, Yj / 2, n - 1);
    hilbertCurve(
      x + Xi / 2 + Yi / 2,
      y + Xj / 2 + Yj / 2,
      Xi / 2,
      Xj / 2,
      Yi / 2,
      Yj / 2,
      n - 1
    );
    hilbertCurve(
      x + Xi / 2 + Yi,
      y + Xj / 2 + Yj,
      -Yi / 2,
      -Yj / 2,
      -Xi / 2,
      -Xj / 2,
      n - 1
    );
  }
};

hilbertCurve(0, 0, bw, 0, 0, bh, 7);

let nextLine = 0;
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate() {
  if (nextLine < lines.length) {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  const prevLine = nextLine - 1 > -1 ? lines[nextLine - 1] : lines[nextLine];
  const line = lines[nextLine];
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(
    prevLine.x + (prevLine.Xi + prevLine.Yi) / 2,
    prevLine.y + (prevLine.Xj + prevLine.Yj) / 2
  );
  ctx.lineTo(
    line.x + (line.Xi + line.Yi) / 2,
    line.y + (line.Xj + line.Yj) / 2
  );
  ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
  ctx.stroke();
  nextLine++;
}

animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="board"></canvas>
```